# How does Shortest Remaining Time First (SRTF) work?

Tags: scheduler, scheduling

If a job is being processed, wouldn't it have the smallest time till completion, since it will just end up as the head of the Ready-to-Run Queue, when it is preempted?

So is this just a repeating cycle till a job has reached completion, with overheads?

Wouldn't longer processes be neglected (just like SJF)?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read the first couple of paragraphs from the [SRTF Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_remaining_time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a job being processed doesn't necessarily have the shortest remaining time.
SRTF checks if there's a process in the ready queue which has less burst time to complete to do the preemption. Let's say you have p1,p2 and p3. p1 has a total burst of 15 and arrives at time 0, p2 has a burst of 10 and arrives at time 3, p3 has a burst of 1 and arrives at time 4.

The execution with SRTF would be:

```
p1 -> from 0 to 3, remaining burst -> p1 = 12
```

at 3, arrives p2, p2 burst < p1 remaining burst, so p2 gets the cpu

```
p2 -> from 3 to 4, remaining burst -> p1=12,p2 = 9
```

at 4 arrives p3, p3 burst < p2 remaining burst < p1 remaining burst, so p3 gets the cpu

```
p3-> from 4 to 5, remaining burst -> p2=9,p1=12
```

```
p2-> from 5 to 14, remaining burst -> p1=12
```

```
p1-> from 14 to 26, end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just wanted to clarify then wouldn't longer processes be neglected as new shorter jobs come in (Jobs preventing the completion of P1) ? Wouldn't this be like Shortest Job First?

Comment: 1) Yes, longer processes may end up starving. 2) SJF doesn't do the preemption based on the remaining time, in SJF preemption is based on the burst time, you can check the other differences at this [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-sjf-and-srjf-cpu-scheduling-algorithms/).

Comment: 2) With the same arrange of processes of the answer, the execution with SJF would be ```P1 from 0 to 12,P3 from 12 to 13 and P2 from 13 to 23```

Comment: Appreciate the clarification